# What is this little, spiky tree?

Tags: identification, trees, tree-care

A friend of mine is moving out and he left me his little tree. Nevertheless, I do not know what kind of tree it is, and I'd like to know so I can google some tips of how to take care of it.

[image: unknown tree]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *Dracaena marginata*. Very easy plant. It needs a little bit of water, not too much. I water it weekly. And light, but it can handle shade as well.

Your plant may benefit from a larger pot, repot it with fresh soil.

Comment: Great advice, thanks! I don't even need to google anymore now. :D 
Just one more question - is it better to be on direct sunlight? Just so I know whether to put it right next to the window or if it can stay where it is now (it's still very bright in there, as you can see, but direct sun rays don't fall on it).

Comment: The plant will survive both direct sunlight and shade. But direct sun light will give you a healthier looking plant, so if you can give it some direct sun light, I would advice you to do that. However, too much light can also cause burn. So a little bit of direct sun light, but not whole day would be best.

Comment: Morning or evening sunlight only... it doesn't  like to be in a lot of sun, especially not  in the middle of the day, but  really, they prefer very bright daylight, not direct sun - but will grow in shadier situations.

Comment: Well, I'm in Denmark, so a burn or too much direct sunlight will _definitely_ not be a problem. :D